# What does the input-events tag in coordinator.xml do?

Tags: hadoop, scheduler, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am trying to understand a coordinator.xml, but not able to understand what does the input-events tag do.can you please help me in understanding, when will this workflow get triggered.

```
<coordinator-app name="MY_APP" frequency="5" start="2009-02-01T00:00Z" end="2009-02-07T00:00Z" timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
   <datasets>
      <dataset name="input1" frequency="5" initial-instance="2009-01-01T00:00Z" timezone="UTC">
         <uri-template>hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/revenue_feed/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}/${HOUR}/${MINUTE}</uri-template>
      </dataset>
   </datasets>
   <input-events>
      <data-in name="coordInput1" dataset="input1">
          <start-instance>${coord:minutes(-10)}</start-instance>
          <end-instance>${coord:current(-5)}</end-instance>
      </data-in>
   </input-events>
   <action>
      <workflow>
         <app-path>hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/workflows</app-path>
      </workflow>
   </action>     
</coordinator-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<input-events>` defines which datasets should be considered for the run by giving a range of dataset instances with `<start-instance>` and `<end-instance>`. These dataset instances are defined in your `<dataset>` block.

`${coord:current(0)}` is the dataset that is closest in time but not later than the coordinator's nominal time. `${coord:current(-1)}` refers to the dataset before `${coord:current(0)}`.

I'm not sure if your example is correct because it uses `${coord:minutes()}`. I believe only `current(n)` or `latest(n)` is supported inside `<input-events>`. Even if minutes(n) was supported, your range does not look correct because your start and end interval are backwards. Meaning, `coord:minutes(-10)` is closer to the present than `coord:current(-5)` if your dataset frequency is 5 minutes.

In my experience this is the most complex topic in Oozie, and I haven't mastered this concept myself. I recommend the O'Reilly Media book *Apache Oozie*. It will give you much more detail about this topic.